# Top Starred comments from the chat :)

Tags: discussion

I was reading the starred comments from [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) and found them so hilarious I thought I might reproduce them here.

This is what **The Ink Spot** is talking about (unofficial name for the thread: "S**t Designers Say")

> ---
>
> - "I project more confidence in **font-identification** than I usually do in
>     real life" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=11233677#11233677)
>
> ---
>
> - "You won't be able to google your own address without landing on this
>     question **that's how potent it will be**" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=11187199#11187199)
>
> ---
>
> - "Possible conspiracy: Adobe controls the development of Inkscape and
>     purposefully makes it lousy to promote Illustrator"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10816388#10816388)
>
> ---
>
> - "That is **how I would do it**, whether or not that is the best way is not
>     something you should ask me"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10892052#10892052)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> - "If Joonas dies do we split his reputation?" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=9986196#9986196)
>
> ---
>
> - "There's a Paul Valery quote that goes, '**An artist never finishes his
>     work, he merely abandons it**'"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10598263#10598263)
>
> ---
>
> - "I burnt my onions looking at your font"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=11233639#11233639)
>
> ---
>
> - "Amazing how far we've come with gummy bear technology" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=9749531#9749531)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> - "I remember my days as a prepress I made the mistake and **whispered
>     sweet nothings to the plate maker** that wasnt working and my boss saw
>     me.. that was ackwardness for about a week" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10572196#10572196)
>
> ---
>
> - "Yeah...people say "**good** is the enemy of **great**" but I think **perfect** is
>     the enemy of either of 'em"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=11152114#11152114)
>
> ---
>
> - "I know I'm a terrible designer :) I can put into form what you
>     describe. But when I get clients who tell me "**Go wild! Design your
>     heart out!**" I'm like uuuuhmmmmmmm yeah lemme go hit up Fotolia" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=9872539#9872539)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> - "Anyone ever hear **if candle smells actually play a role in productivity?**" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10426765#10426765)
>
> ---
>
> - "Every design I've ever seen on **dribble** just looks like pretentious
>     trend following"
>     [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=11098262#11098262)
>
> ---
>
> - "Everyone is part of some stereotype. We can't control that because its
>     the perception of others not our own" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=9677612#9677612)
>
> ---
>
> - "I **powerlift** my mouse every day" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=9677571#9677571)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---

And my favorite one:

> - "**Roses will bloom without stop until they kill themselves.**" [...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=10205534#10205534)

Comment: It's true. @Scott *does* know everything. I thought we had moved to rename this the Scott Stack Exchange once he cleared 25K rep?

Comment: For the record, I do not know everything, only half of everything. My brother knows the other half.

Answer (score 2):

@Scott knows everything picture is really amazing and it made my day. Yes I also want the Scott Stack Exchange. I know this post going to down vote are anything, but the above chat comments are nice.